# Stopping criteria/rule for ADAM optimization in pytorch?

Tags: python, optimization, gradient, pytorch, gradient-descent

In the code below, we define two functions, and then do some optimization using adam and pytorch. The code seems to work. However, we do a pre-defined number of iterations for the adam optimization (see the while loop). How can we put a stopping criteria based on the output of the optimization? An example for such criteria we are trying to use is that the improvement of the objective function is smaller than a given threshold or anything similar.

```
import torch
import torch.optim as optim

def myFirstFunction(parameter_current_here):
    optimalValue=100000000000000
    for j in range(2,10):
        i= torch.ones(1,requires_grad=True)*j
        optimalValueNow=i*parameter_current_here.sum()
        if (optimalValueNow<optimalValue):
            optimalValue=optimalValueNow

    return optimalValueNow,i

def mySecondFunction(Current):
    y=(20*Current)/2 + (Current**2)/10
    return y

parameter_current = torch.randn(2, 2,requires_grad=True)
optimizer = optim.Adam([parameter_current], lr = 0.1)
counter=0
while counter<5:
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputMyFirstFunction=myFirstFunction(parameter_current)
    outputmySecondFunction=mySecondFunction(outputMyFirstFunction[0]) 
    outputmySecondFunction.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print("outputMyFirstFunction after backward:",outputMyFirstFunction)
    print("outputmySecondFunction after backward:",outputmySecondFunction)
    print("parameter_current Gradient after backward:",parameter_current.grad)

    counter=counter+1
```

Your help will be greatly appreciate.
Thanks,
Aly

Comment: Why don't you check a loss or metrics for early stopping?

Comment: Can you please provide an example code for that maybe, in the context of my example?